# PHP Jquery Dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I was following this tutorial from this [website](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-how-to-make-dependent-dropdown-list-using-jquery-ajaxexample.html) and ran into some trouble. I'm doing this for a car website. So everything works correctly that only problem is that how would I create a Go button to view that correct from the drop-down.

So the drop=down goes a bit like this.

Make -> list all cars in the make. once they chose that car a 'Go' button appears to visit only that car. The go button will just be a link with CSS that looks like a button. Here is the code that make the cars appear.

State = Make

City = Car

```
<script>
$( "select[name='state']" ).change(function () {
var stateID = $(this).val();


if(stateID) {


    $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxpro.php",
        dataType: 'Json',
        data: {'id':stateID},
        success: function(data) {
            $('select[name="city"]').empty();
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                $('select[name="city"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
            });
        }
    });


}else{
    $('select[name="city"]').empty();
}
});
```

Comment: Post your code not the tutorial code.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please clarify. Post the relevant HTML also.

Answer (score 0):

how to create a Go button? if taht's the question, then, As you say "The go button will just be a link with CSS that looks like a button"..

if the question is, "how that button will work"? can be just an onclick function that load the view of cars, and send to that view the selected value of the dropdown.